# Найти индекс первого положительного элемента не используя цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, -4, 2, -2, -6, 5]
for i in x:
    if i > 0:
        print("Перший додатній елемент: ", i)
        break
print(x.index(i))
```

Я написал этот код, но узнал что нельзя использовать цикл. Как найти индекс только первого положительного элемента?

Comment: этот код выдаст ошибку

Comment: что "нет"?.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Во первых, у Вас действительно есть синтаксическая ошибка. Надо писать так:

```
print(x.index(i))
```

Ну а по сути, без цикла можно задачу решить так:

```
x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, -4, 2, -2, -6, 5]

b = list(filter(lambda z: z > 0, x))
print(b[0])
```

Comment: Код  ответе печатает значение первого положительного числа, но не его индекс. В вопросе просили индекс.

Answer (score 2):

Ищем индекс первого положительного элемента: `enumerate` выдаёт пары (индекс, значение), `if` из них отбирает положительные значения, `next` отбирает только первый индекс.

```
x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, -4, 2, -2, -6, 5]

print(next(i for i, v in enumerate(x) if v > 0))
#     ^    ^ ------------------------ --------
#     |    | ^                        ^
#     |    | |                        отбираем только положительные значения
#     |    | |
#     |    | перебираем пары (индекс, значение)
#     |    |
#     |    значение не нужно, возвращаем только индекс
#     |
#     все индексы не нужны, только первый
```

Результат:

```
@>>> x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, -4, 2, -2, -6, 5]

@>>> print(*enumerate(x))
(0, -3) (1, -5) (2, 3) (3, 4) (4, -4) (5, 2) (6, -2) (7, -6) (8, 5)

@>>> print(*((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(x)))
(0, -3) (1, -5) (2, 3) (3, 4) (4, -4) (5, 2) (6, -2) (7, -6) (8, 5)

@>>> print(*((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(x) if v > 0))
(2, 3) (3, 4) (5, 2) (8, 5)

@>>> print(*(i for i, v in enumerate(x) if v > 0))
2 3 5 8

@>>> print(next(i for i, v in enumerate(x) if v > 0))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Или можно решить вот так:

```
from functools import reduce
x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, -4, 2, -2, -6, 5]
b = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b if a==0 and b>0 else a, x, 0)
print(b)
```

Если нужен индекс. а не значение, то лямбду подправить на:
lambda a, b: a + x.index(b), остальное без изменений.

Comment: Нужно индекс, а не сам элемент.

Comment: @Эникейщик  Ну значит лямбду чуть подправить: lambda a, b: a + x.index(b) ...  остальное без изменений.

Comment: Да можно было и просто print подправить

Answer (score 1):

в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219975/400096) от участника [Sergey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213498/sergey), берутся все положительные значения, хотя лучше взять только первое

```
x = [-3, -5, 3, 4, -4, 2, -2, -6, 5]

b = next(filter(lambda z: z > 0, x))
print(b)
```